# Special characters as \pounds in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, symbols

I have some items with \pounds and the Russian ruble sign in the title which I want to refer to in the bibliography with bibtex. How can I succeed?

Comment: Use `biblatex` and `biber`. They understand `utf8`.

Comment: For £ you should be able to say `\textsterling`. For the Ruble symbol there is no such command, so you may want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/260722/35864. Theoretically you could also use the Unicode code points, but then you need a font with the glyphs. `biblatex` and Biber officially support Unicode. If you want to use BibTeX, you should be fine using Unicode symbols as long as you don't expect them to sort properly (though Unicode is not officially supported).

Comment: `fontawesome` has a `\faRuble` command.